# Why does Dispatchqueue.main.async still excute the block in main thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading

```
import UIKit

let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")


serialQueue.async {
    print("Custom Serial Queue - \(Thread.isMainThread)") // print false
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("Main Queue - \(Thread.isMainThread)") // print true
}
```

I know when we use .async to execute the task
 
we won't block the main thread

It's because we execute the block in background thread 
 
and update the main thread when it is finished

MainQueue is a kind of "serial queue" also
 
but why we use "DispatchQueue.main.async" , it's still execute task in main thread

the custom serial queue can do that in background thread?

Comment: DispatchQueue.main when you write means whatever you code within this block will execute in main thread. .main means code will execute in main thread

Comment: I recommend https://medium.com/@KentaKodashima/swift-grand-central-dispatch-gcd-80bcb16a147f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> I know when we use `.async` to execute the task we won't block the main thread.

Yes, we often dispatch asynchronously to a background queue to avoid blocking the main thread. But, more accurately, we technically use `async` to avoid blocking the *current* thread. Sure, if you’re on the main thread, that means we’re not blocking the main thread. But if you’re currently running on a background thread, then `async` just keeps you from blocking that current background thread.

> ... but why we use `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

This is commonly used when you’re already on a background thread, but have something (like a UI update) that must be run on the main thread. Then you’d dispatch that UI update from the background thread back to the main queue. And we’d generally do this asynchronously because there’s no point in having that background thread wait for the UI update.

E.g.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    // do something computationally intensive here ...

    // ... but when you want to update the UI with the result, you’d dispatch that back to the main queue

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = ...
    }
}
```

Or you’d use the same pattern when using `URLSession` (or anything that runs on a background thread). We’d use `DispatchQueue.main.async` if we’re currently on some background thread, but need to perform UI updates, which must always happen on the main thread. So we’d dispatch those UI updates back to the main queue.

That’s why we use `DispatchQueue.main.async`. That having been said, while there is rarely any utility to it, you technically can dispatch asynchronously from the main thread back to itself, like you have in your question. All that will happen is that the dispatched code will be added to the end of the main queue, but won’t run until you finish whatever you were previously doing on the main thread.

For example, imagine that the following is run on the main thread

```
print("a")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("b")
}
print("c")
```

You’ll see “a”, the `print("b")` will be queued (but not run yet), you’ll then carry on the main thread and will see “c”. Then when you eventually yield back to the app’s run loop, only then will the main thread be freed so that `print("b")` can be performed. So you’ll see “a” and “c”, first, and then “b”!

Comment: so we can consider the "main queue" is a kind very special serail queue, not same as "custom serial queue" that can perform task asynchronously on back ground thread?

Comment: Exactly. The `main` queue is one that always runs tasks dispatched to it on the main thread. A “custom serial queue” is one that you create to run tasks on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , this problem confused me for a long time

Comment: No problem. FYI, the [Concurrency Programming Guide: Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) has a nice discussion of the types of queues. Unfortunately, all of the code snippets are for Objective-C, but it covers the concepts well. The [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/) video is a good conceptual introduction for Swift users, too, visually representing what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

DispatchQueue.main.async {...} will execute its code block in main thread. DispatchQueue.global().async {...} for example will execute it in background thread with lower priority